# R Creating a list of multiple dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, directory

I need to extract column 2 from a list of multiple dataframe. 
I have 18 files and I was able to do it by reading each file separately.

```
df1 <- read.table("name.XLS", header = FALSE)
df2 <- read.table("name.XLS", header = FALSE)
df3 <- read.table("name.XLS", header = FALSE)
df4 <- read.table("name.XLS", header = FALSE)

data_list = list(df1, df2,df3,df4)
# extract column named V2
res = lapply(data_list, '[[', 2)
# convert to character
res = lapply(res, as.character)
```

I modified the code to read all files in the directory

```
folder <- "temp"  
file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.XLS") 

for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  assign(file_list[i], 
         read.csv(paste(folder, file_list[i], sep="/"))
  )}
```

I need to create an equivalent list to data_list that reads a list of multiple dataframe to extract column V2 from each dataframe in the list

**EDIT**

I tried the following code and it worked just fine

```
my_data <- lapply(file_list, read.table)
```

You can find more about lists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3373710)

Comment: Do you need all data.frame or only column 2?

Comment: I needed dataframes with all variables and columns. I found the answer and  I have modified the question. Thank you!

Comment: Try `data_list <- lapply(file.path(folder, file_list), read.csv, sep="/")`

Comment: @lukeA worked, but wasn't able to extract V2. I changed it to read.table but still the same